# How to change root path in deployment in AWS-EC2 Ubuntu Linux using Apache 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Once we deploy our Rails app to AWS-EC2,but when we did our routing went all haywire. Rails wants www.example.com/ to be the root. We want www.example.com/myapp to be rails root path.

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :forms do
    collection do
      post :accept_item
    end
  end
  resources :stores, m:'true'
  match '/send_mail', to: 'stores#send_mail', via: 'post'
  get 'products' => 'products#index', m:'true'
  get 'stores' => 'stores#index', m:'true'
  get 'transactions' => 'transactions#index', m:'true'
  get 'inventories' => 'inventories#index', m:'true'
  get 'about' => 'sites#about'
  get 'man' => 'sites#index', m:'true'
  root 'sites#index'

end
```

Comment: Can you paste your apache config file too for the above application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap all of your routes in the routes file inside a scope such as:

```
scope path: '/myapp' do
  #routes here
end
```